# Merge the tags [indexoutofrangeexception] and [outofrangeexception]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

There are these two tags:

- [indexoutofrangeexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofrangeexception) with 399 questions.
- [outofrangeexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outofrangeexception) with 250 questions.

These tags have very similar tag wiki excerpt and also are used for the same type of questions.

Both of them are used for the "Index out of range" errors in many different programming languages.

These tags have occurred together in [6 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofrangeexception+outofrangeexception).

My suggestion is to synonymize these two tags to each other.

These two tags are most often used for questions about the index out of range exceptions of C++, Python and C#.

I believe these two tags should be kept, but one should be synonymized to the other. In my opinion the ideal solution would be to tag them all as [outofrangeexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outofrangeexception).

Or as mentioned by @Vickel, maybe with hyphens it would work better, like [out-of-range-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/out-of-range-exception).

Comment: or for better readability: [tag:out-of-range-exception]

Comment: Seems reasonable. I agree with @Vickel though. The hyphen separated version is much more readable (though that's an easy fix). I can put the synonym in place in a couple days if no one raises any objections here.

Comment: I also like the ` out-of-range-exception` version better.

Comment: Most other tags about exceptions are not hyphenated, though. [[tag:nullpointerexception]], [[tag:nullreferenceexception]], [[tag:classnotfoundexception]], [[tag:filenotfoundexception]], [[tag:classcastexception]], [[tag:illegalstateexception]], [[tag:illegalargumentexception]], [[tag:sqlexception]], [[tag:numberformatexception]], [[tag:socketexception]], [[tag:nosuchelementexception]], [[tag:sslhandshakeexception]], [[tag:invalidoperationexception]], [[tag:timeoutexception]], [[tag:securityexception]], [[tag:inputmismatchexception]]

Comment: And then there's all these w/ hyphens: [tag:unhandled-exception], [tag:inflate-exception], [tag:uncaught-exception], [tag:socket-timeout-exception], [tag:interrupted-exception], [tag:expected-exception], [tag:first-chance-exception], [tag:unchecked-exception], [tag:inner-exception], [tag:structured-exception], [tag:unobserved-exception], [tag:corrupted-state-exception], [tag:flutter-exception], [tag:boost-exception], [tag:catch-exception], [tag:elasticsearch-exception], [tag:ebnf-syntactic-exception], [tag:constructor-exception], [tag:version-conflict-engine-exception], [tag:generic-exception]

Comment: So.... maybe we need to have a separate discussion about which way we want these to be generally.

Comment: since I'm speaking Portuguese, the [tag: outofrangeexception] seemed to me really unclear, as I read something like *outrofrango* (another chicken) into it at the 1st glance :). So I really would prefer the hyphenated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created the synonym. [indexoutofrangeexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/indexoutofrangeexception) now points to [outofrangeexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outofrangeexception).

I've not merged the tags yet. I'll do this in a few weeks if no one objects. I'm going to give more time for users to either support the proposal or provide feedback, it's a busy time of year for people and I want to make sure everyone who wants to has the ability to provide input. The synonym is easily reversible the merge is significantly less so.

---

I'm not going to rename the tags here to include hyphens (at this time), though I really do think there would be benefit in having a conversation about how we want our tags to appear in general.